# node.js on VPS Hosting using Hostgator

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was about to upload my almost finished website and went on to purchase a VPS Hosting.
Hostgator confirmed that they support Node.js and I found myself in a big question mark.
Am i uploading it correctly or what is failing?

Folder View contains: Index.ejs
Folder Public contains: All the CSS, JS, Images and Form related to Index.ejs

Upon calling the Website everything renders properly until i get into the add to cart section and this line of code appear:

```
 <% items.Salat.forEach(function(item){ %>
```

and so on

```
<%= item.description %>
```

[image: FTP]

Answer (score 2):

Your VPS' operating system appears to have come with a webserver preinstalled. It has a `phpinfo.php` file which suggests it has an extension set up for running PHP programs. (There's a good chance that it is Apache HTTPD with mod_php).

Server-side programs that use Node.js run directly through Node.js and not through an extension on an existing webserver.

Typically you would either disable the existing webserver and run the one written in Node.js **instead** or configure the existing webserver to act as a *reverse proxy* which forwards requests to the Node.js server.

Either way, you can't just drop your JS source code into the webserver's directory root and have it execute it.